# Assembly Language Arrays

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86, masm

This is a pretty simple question.. lets say I have the following.

```
wordArray WORD 810Dh, 0C064h, 93ABh
```

Now, if I do this...

```
MOVZX EAX, wordArray
```

Thats going to move the first value of the array onto EAX.. so EAX would look something like this.. 0000810D. My question is, how can I move ALL of the array onto EAX.. so EAX would look like this... 810DC06493AB .. I think. Is this possible?

Comment: Use NASM, it has a much cleaner syntax.

Comment: @ruslik .. if only. I am forced to program MASM for a course Im taking. But, the libraries that I get to use make MASM not so terrible either.

Comment: @ruslik: is NASM the same as AT&T syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, EAX only holds 32 bits, so at most it would only hold two of the elements.  What you want to do in this case is to use the regular `MOV` instruction:

```
MOV EAX, dword ptr wordArray.
```

This will put 32 bits starting from the offset at wordArray into EAX.